# Passing values through hidden fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I have a form using rails and angular. There are hidden inputs, where the values are set using rails, and I want them bound and sent to angular:

```
= f.hidden_field :taskable_id, value: @patient.id, 
'ng-model' => 'newTask.taskable_id'

= f.hidden_field :taskable_type, value: @patient.class.to_s,
'ng-model' => 'newTask.taskable_type'

= f.hidden_field :creator_id, value: current_user.id,
'ng-model' => 'newTask.creator_id'
```

The problem I'm having is that (from what I've read), angular ignores hidden fields. Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot have two-way data-binding with a hidden field (thus `ng-model` won't work; nor would it make much sense in the general case).

You could use "normal", one-way binding using interpolation in the hidden input's `value` attribute:

```
<input type="hidden" name="hiddenField" value="{{hiddenValue}}" />
```

See this **[GitHub issue](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/2574)** for more info.

---

In your case (where you also want to initialize `hiddenValue` to some value), you can use **[`ng-init`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angInit)**. E.g. set the `taskable_id` field's value to `"{{newTask.taskable_id}}"`, omit the `ng-model` attribute (as it won't have any effect) and set the `ng-init` attribute to `"newTask.taskable_id = " + @patient.id` (sorry, I am not sure about the Rails syntax).

The end-result should look like this:

```
<input type="hidden" ... value="{{newTask.taskable_id}}"
       ng-init="newTask.taskable_id = <someID>" />
```

This will initialize `newTask.taskable_id` to `<someID>` and set the value of the hidden field to it.
See, also, this **[short demo](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angInit)** (regarding the end-result).

Comment: I have also used this approach. Use angular js binding and update the data from controller/scope.

Answer (score 0):

It is not AngularJs way, as I think. I would provide some sort of REST API in rails for angular.

You may declare your service and use [$http](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24http) to consume your data from rails.